# Using two monitors, Ubuntu isn't very 'snappy'/responsive any more?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've recently hooked up a second monitor to my laptop, and for some reason, Ubuntu isn't very snappy any more. There's a very slight lag between me doing an action and it showing up. For example, after typing a letter, there's a tiny delay between me pressing the button and it showing up on the screen. It's not a huge issue, but it gets quite annoying.

I doubt it's my actual system, as it's fairly high end. A6-3400M AMD processor, 16gb ram, AMD Radeon 6540G2 (1gn VRAM) Graphics card. Also, I'm using Gnome shell instead of Unity. I don't have any fancy Compiz settings, etc installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: is Unity-3d running at all? I had the same problem, then i switched to unity-2d and my performance was fine

Comment: This unanswered question is 5+ years old and OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years to respond to comments seeking additional information. As it is about EOL Ubuntu 12.04 or something older VTC as `not reproducible`.